# jBPM: No Such Method Error While Creating Runtime Engine

Tags: jbpm

I am trying to use Kie API to retrieve task info using this code and getting an exception.

```
    String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server";
    String user = "kieserver";
    String password = "kieserver1!";

    String containerId = "hr";
    String processId = "hiring";
    RemoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory remoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory =   
          RemoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory.newBuilder()
              .addDeploymentId("com.myspace:MyScriptProject:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
                .addUrl(new URL(serverUrl))
                .addUserName(user)
                .addPassword(password)
                .build();

  RemoteRuntimeEngine engine = remoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory.newRuntimeEngine();

  KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();

  TaskService taskService = engine.getTaskService();
  Task t= taskService.getTaskById(111);
```

The exceptions are one of these depending on which jars are used and how the remoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory is assigned:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jbpm.services.task.impl.command.CommandBasedTaskService.<init>(Lorg/drools/core/command/CommandService;Lorg/jbpm/services/task/events/TaskEventSupport;)V
            at org.kie.services.client.api.command.RemoteRuntimeEngine.getTaskService(RemoteRuntimeEngine.java:29)



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.kie.services.client.serialization.jaxb.impl.JaxbCommandsRequest.setVersion(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

These are the jars I have in the classpath.

```
commons-logging-1.2.jar   
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m02.jar   
httpclient-4.2.1.jar  
httpcore-4.2.1.jar  
resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.4.Final.jar  
jbpm-audit-7.33.0.Final.jar  
drools-core-6.0.0.cr1.jar  
kie-services-jaxb-6.1.0.Beta 1.jar 
javax.jms-api-2.0.jar   
org.slf4j.jar   
kie-server-common-7.33.0.Final.jar  
kie-services-client-6.1.0.Final.jar  
kie-remote-jaxb-6.3.0.Final.jar  
jbpm-human-task-core-6.5.0.Final.jar  
kie-server-api-6.5.0.Final.jar 
kie-api-6.5.0.CR2.jar   
kie-server-client-6.5.0.Final.jar  
kie-internal-6.5.0.Final.jar
```

Apparently I am mixing some newer and older jars that are causing the exceptions. May be you have a better suggestion other than by trial-and-error. Thanks for reading

Comment: Please see https://developer.jboss.org/thread/251501 for a similar issue. Apparently I am not alone :(

Comment: I have made code cleanup for  better readability.